# Error with mixed derivatives during derivation of Laplacian in polar coordinates

Tags: partial-derivative, polar-coordinates, laplacian

It can be shown that, if $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function and the Cartesian and polar coordinates are related by
$$
x = \rho\cos\phi\\
y = \rho\sin\phi
$$
that $\partial f/\partial x$ may be written (using the chain rule) like
$$
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \cos\phi\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \rho} - \dfrac{\sin\phi}{\rho}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} \tag{1}
$$
Because $\partial f/\partial \rho:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is also smooth, we can replace $f$ by $\partial f/\partial \rho$ in equation $(1)$, implying that smooth functions also obey
$$
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}\right) = \cos\phi\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial\rho^2} - \dfrac{\sin\phi}{\rho} \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial\phi\partial\rho} \tag{2}
$$
However, when I try to calculate $(2)$ by mixing up the order of differentiation, I get an extra term:
$$
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\rho}\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)
 &= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\rho}\left( \cos\phi\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \rho} - \dfrac{\sin\phi}{\rho} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} \right) \\
 &= \cos\phi\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial\rho^2} - \dfrac{\sin\phi}{\rho}\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial\rho\partial\phi} + \dfrac{\sin\phi}{\rho^2}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} \tag{3}
\end{align*}
$$
So could anybody please explain to me why expression $(2)$ and $(3)$ are not the same?

Comment: Judging by what you have written, your function $f$ is written in polar coordinates, and you want to take a derivative in terms of Cartesian coordinates, right? In this case, $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{\cos \phi}$, which I think you've written as $\cos \phi$ in (1). Similarly, $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = \frac{-1}{\rho \sin \phi}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the order of differentiation with respect to a pair of variables belonging to different coordinate systems! While it's true that $f''_{xy}=f''_{yx}$ and $f''_{\rho\phi}=f''_{\phi\rho}$ (if $f$ is nice enough), there is no reason to believe that $f''_{\rho x} = f''_{x \rho}$, and in fact it's **not true** in general, as simple examples show.

Remember that taking a partial derivative with respect to $x$ involves keeping $y$ constant, and taking a partial derivative with respect to $\rho$ involves keeping $\phi$ constant, so even if the "partner variables" $y$ and $\phi$ are not "visible" in the expressions $f''_{\rho x}$ and $f''_{x \rho}$, they are very much a part of the game.